# Connection Pool

Tags: java, thread-safety, connection, connection-pooling

```
 BlockingQueue<Connection> connections = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Connection>(maxConnection);

AtomicInteger numberOfDrewedConnectionFromPool
```

In my ConnectionPool i use LinkedBlockingQueue. I have some doubt whether multiply  "if statement" will be thread-safe. maxConnection is constant. numberOfDrewedConnectionFromPool changes also in method releaseConection without lock()..

```
 public Connection getConnection() throws ConnectionPoolException {
    Connection connection = null;

    if ((connections.poll() == null) && (maxConnection > numberOfDrewedConnectionFromPool.get())) {
        return newConnection();
    } else {
        return connections.poll();
    }
}


private Connection newConnection() throws ConnectionPoolException {
    lock.lock();
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            numberOfDrewedConnectionFromPool.incrementAndGet();
        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            throw new ConnectionPoolException();
        }
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
        return connection;
    }

}
```

Comment: Like JB Nizet suggested, use an existing connection pool like http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/ for example. Implementing this yourself is a waste of time, and hard if not impossible to get right.

Comment: own conectionPool is requirement of task)

Comment: Is it homework? If it's not, explain your boss that existing connection pools exist, and that he's losing money by trying to implement a connection pool.

Answer (score 1):

No, your code is not thread-safe.

Between the time where `connections.poll()` is called and the time where the number of connections is compared to the max, some other thread might have released or taken a connection, and the number of connections might have changed. 
Moreover, you're polling the queue twice to get a single connection.

Side note: why are you reinventing the wheel? There are plenty of free connection pools available.

Comment: Have you some thought about that...
1. When are creating connectionPool collection must be full of connection or not?

2. Connection have to remove from pool? I have idea use peek() but i don't now whether it automatically send used connection to head queue. Also possible make some ConnectionWrapper which have boolean field used or unsed...

Comment: 1. It depends. Most connection pools are configurable in this area (min, max, starting number of connections). 2. No. The connection pool should contain all the connections, used or not (but must of course be able to distinguish used and unused connections. Don't implement a connection pool. Reuse an existing one.

Comment: I don't understand your question. All I'm saying is: don't develop a connection pool. Use an existing implementation like c3p0 or dbcp.

Comment: Ufhhh... i don't have idea for your requirement. Have you say me some things which i can use for starting my development of pool?